# PHP move to section

Tags: php

Okay, so I have a PHP script which is a contact form (as shown below)

```
$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
if ($_POST['submit']) {
if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
    if ($human == '4') {                 
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    } 
} else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
    echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
}
} else {
    echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!</p>';
  }
 }
?>
```

And I was wondering (since I'm not very experienced in PHP) if there was a way to  bring me back to the div where the contact form is if there was an error?
Thanks in advance
EDIT: HTML CODE:
http://pastebin.com/CwXsDapB

Comment: You'll need to output Javascript that uses `document.getElementById('fieldname').focus()`.

Comment: you need to post HTML code to help in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can store your errors in session.

And again redirecting to form.

e.g.

```
$_SESSION['error'] = '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
header("Location:YOUR_FORM.PHP?error#form_div");
```

Add add id `form_div` to div containing your form.

```
<div id="form_div">
<?php
if (! empty($_SESSION['error'])) {
  echo $_SESSION['error'];
  $_SESSION['error'] = '';
}
?>
<form>

...
```

Comment: @pandamason, then please accept my answer as solution.

Comment: Just has a wait time, sorry about that. Also, it seems that when it sends me to the Div, the error message does not pop up at all. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can come back to you contact form on error, 
Is your contact form is on the same page or the other page?

If on the same page, Then I would suggest you to use the validation from Javascript or Jquery, Which will check if the form has values and values are equivalent to any numeric, Then on success you can submit the form.

The below link may help you for validation,

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/practice.cgi?file=javascript_43

If in case if you need to do with PHP and you coming in to different page after form submit you can use

header function from PHP to get it redirect to form page.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Regards, 
V

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for PHP Sessions since you are processing the form in the same page ( seen you have `<form method="POST">` ).

Store your returning message in a `$status` variable for example and then show it as this , before the form and your php page would look like this:

```
<?php
    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
            if ($human == '4') {                 
                if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                $status =  '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
            } else { 
                $status = '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
            } 
        } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
            $status = '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
        }
        } else {
            $status = '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!</p>';
        }
    }
    echo ($status) ? '<div id="status">'.$status.'</div>' : '';
?>
<form action="" method="POST"> 
        <label>Name</label>
        <br>
        <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">
    </div>
    <div>   
        <label>Email</label>
        <br>
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Message</label>
        <br>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div> 
        <label>*What is 2+2? (Spam protection)</label>
        <br>
        <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here">
    </div>

    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```